# Bartle taxonomy formula

Tags: game-design, mmo, psychology

Anyone knows the formula inside the Bartle Test of players taxonomy?

I need to do the test, but I need the weight of each question to make something more accurate and trustworthy to the real test...

Some links to the online test:

- http://matthewbarr.co.uk/bartle/
- http://4you2learn.com/bartle/

Comment: I wouldn't take the Bartle taxonomy that serious. There is a bit of each of the four types in every player. Which role they prefer depends on the game and on their current mood. You should rather see it as a simplified mental model to better understand player motivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erwin Andreasen, the co-author of the widely-taken questionnaire, [links to the original question set](http://www.andreasen.org/mud.shtml) (which seems to be the same one used on the sites you linked). Since the download link is somewhat hidden in an auto-redirect page, I'll just reproduce it in full here:

```
Are you more comfortable, as a player on a MUD:
+S Talking with friends in a tavern?
+A Out hunting orcs by yourself for experience?


Which is more enjoyable to you?
+A Killing a big monster
+S Bragging about it to your friends?


Which do you enjoy more in MUD quests:
+S Getting involved in the storyline
+A Getting the rewards at the end?


Which would you rather be noticed for on a MUD?:
+A Your equipment
+S Your personality


Would you rather be:
+S Popular
+A Wealthy


Which do you enjoy more on a MUD?:
+S Getting the latest gossip
+A Getting a new item


Which would you rather have, as a player on a MUD?:
+S A private channel, over which you and your friends can communicate
+A Your own house, worth millions of gold coins

Which would you enjoy more as a MUD player?
+S Running your own tavern?
+E Making your own maps of the world, then selling them?


What's more important in a MUD to you?
+S The number of people
+E The number of areas to explore


What's more important to you:
+S The quality of roleplaying in a mud
+E The uniqueness of the features, and game mechanic


You are being chased by a monster on a MUD.
Do you:
+S Ask a friend for help in killing it
+E Hide somewhere you know the monster won't follow

You're a player on a mud, and you want to fight a really tough dragon.
How would you approach this problem?
+S Get a big group of players to kill it.
+E Try a variety of weapons and magic against it, until you find its weakness.

You're a player on a mud, and about to go into an unknown dungeon.
You have your choice of one more person for your party.
Do you bring:
+S A bard, who's a good friend of yours and who's great for entertaining you and your friends
+E A wizard, to identify the items that you find there

Is it better to be:
+K Feared
+S Loved

Someone has PK'ed you. Do you want to:
+S Find out why, and try to convince them not to do it again
+K Plot your revenge

Which is more exciting?
+S A well-roleplayed scenario
+K A deadly battle

Which would you enjoy more?
+K Winning a duel with another player
+S Getting accepted by a clan

Would you rather
+K Vanquish your enemies
+S Convince your enemies to work for you, not against you

What's worse:
+K To be without power
+S To be without friends

Would you rather:
+S Hear what someone has to say
+K Show them the sharp blade of your axe


On a MUD, a new area opens up.
Which do you look forward to more?
+E Exploring the new area, and finding out its history
+A Being the first to get the new equipment from the area

On a MUD, would you rather be known as:
+E Someone who can run from any two points in the world, and really knows their way around.
+A The person with the best, most unique equipment in the game

Would you rather:
+A Become a hero faster than your friends
+E Know more secrets than your friends?

Would you rather:
+E Know where to find things
+A Know how to get things?

Which would you rather do:
+E Solve a riddle no one else has gotten
+A Getting to a certain experience level faster than anyone else

Do you tend to:
+E Know things no one else does
+A Have items no one else does

On a MUD, would rather join a clan of:
+E Scholars
+K Assassins

Would you rather win:
+E A trivia contest
+K An arena battle

If you're alone in an area, do you think:
+E It's safe to explore
+K You'll have to look elsewhere for prey

On a MUD, would rather be known for
+E Knowledge
+K Power

Would you rather:
+K Defeat an enemy
+E Explore a new area

You learn that another player is planning your demise.
Do you:
+E Go to an area your opponent is unfamiliar with and prepare there
+K Attack him before he attacks you

You meet a new player. Do you think of him as:
+E Someone who can appreciate your knowledge of the game
+K As potential prey

On a mud, would you rather:
+A Have a sword twice as powerful as any other in the game
+K Be the most feared person in the game

On a mud, would you be more prone to brag about:
+K How may other players you've killed
+A Your equipment

Would you rather have:
+K A spell to damage other players
+A A spell that increases the rate at which you gain experience points?

Would you rather have:
+A Two levels of experience
+K An amulet that increases the damage you do against other players by 10%.

Would you rather receive as a quest reward:
+A Experience points
+K A wand with 3 charges of a spell that lets you control other players, against their will. (charm person)

When playing a video game, is it more fun to:
+A Have the highest score on the list?
+K Beat your best friend one-on-one?
```

As you can see, there are no weights - each question has equal value, and simply chooses between two quadrants. Add up all the quadrants to get your final score.

Keep in mind that this questionnaire, and the taxonomy itself, is very simplistic and not rigorous at all. There are more accurate models for player psychology available. But as a simple way to understand that there can be different player motivations, this model is fine.

Comment: Woah, thanks for reproducing here, I'll mark your answer 'cause of future compatibility (so the values will be here forever).

Comment: Just to know about, what are these more accurate models? Can you list (maybe link) them?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real "formula".

The original presentation of a "Bartle Test" (as formulated by Erwin Andreasen) is to present the test-taker with a series of situations, and ask them to choose between two options, where each of the two options represents one of the types in Richard Bartle's [Bartle Taxonomy of Player Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartle_taxonomy_of_player_types).

All you do to interpret the test is to add up the number of times the answer for each 'type' was selected.  That's really all there is to it.  There's no formula, no science, and there's no 'more accurate' or 'trustworthy' to be striven for.  It's just a simple pop-culture personality test which gets you to say what you prefer to do, and then parrots back that you seem to be a person who prefers to do the things that you just said you prefer to do.  Ooo, science-y.

The original question data, with the intended scoring for each answer, are available from the website of the test's creator, [here](http://www.andreasen.org/bartle/).  (it's the link labelled "original English question data set")

N.B.: In the original question set (which is used verbatim in both of the links posted in the question), 'Socialiser' and 'Killer' are each available 20 times, while 'Achiever' and 'Explorer' are each only available 19 times.  This biases test results slightly towards producing higher 'Socialiser' and 'Killer' values.  This may give you a hint at the lofty heights of scientific rigour under which this personality test was devised.